# Blockquoting null?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, editor

I was just editing a Stack Overflow question I had answered via the Android app. There I used the rather new feature of these editing buttons. I marked some text (after adding a second space at the end of each line to allow linebreaking) and selected 'format as blockquote'

The result? Some text with broken formatting and previously nonexistant literal 'null' in it:

[image: screen shot]

For reference: [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29225962/1803692)

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta), the texts were indented by 4 spaces. Could you try to repro this again?

Comment: @Anderew I can repro but I am still on 1.81, so it might well have been fixed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

There were actually a series of bugs messing things up here:

1. **We weren't properly recognizing that the text wasn't in a quote.**  We use the regular expression `/^(?![ ]{0,3}>)/m` to check that no lines start with a `>`, but this was incorrectly used in `String.matches` which validates that the whole string matches making the multiline flag kind of useless.  Now we validate with `Pattern.compile("^(?![ ]{0,3}>)").matcher(selection).find()`
2. **Our code for unwrapping markdown strings hit a undefined behavior.**  We use the regular expression `/([^\n])\n(?!(\n|(?:\s{4,}|\s*>|\s*-\s+|\s*\d+\.|=|\+|-|_|\*|#|\s*\[[^]]+\]:)))/gm` with `$1 $2` to convert things like `Hello
   World` to `Hello World` before adding `>`.  The second group in the expression is inside a negative lookahead which means it should never exist.  JavaScript and Objective-C gives us the equivalent of an empty string here but Java gives us `null`.  Since we know `$2` will always be blank, I updated the replacement to `$1` and all is well.
3. **After unwrapping, we rewrap to 70 characters wide.  This code had some issues where it would incorrectly replace lower lines with upper lines.**  This wasn't really hit before because the code never got this far, but that was a problem.
4. **The unwrapping code from 2 did not consider `\r`.**  This caused `\r\n\r\n` to eventually transform to `\n> \r> \n> \r>`.  This isn't the biggest problem because the Markdown processor could handle it, but Android doesn't render stray `\r` as a line break so it looked like you had lines starting with `> >`.  (iOS actually renders them as new lines which has made this bug elusive there.)  Now when unwrapping, we drop carriage returns in the selection entirely.