# Code entry problem in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, editor

I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29223638/4402222) through the **iOS app** without problems. Previously I tried to posted it (exact same text) through the **Android app**, but I got this message:

> **Please fix the following:**
>
> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

My code was properly indented though.

P.S. I didn't use in-app markdown toolbar. I formatted my answer manually. Only after I saw the problem, I tried to use the button for code-block formatting, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you suggesting that iPhones are cooler than Androids? This is a very aggressive statement

Comment: Might be related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251962/blockquoting-null

Comment: @Adel :) I'm trying to switch from iPhone to Android, and it triggers many issues.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the link. I didn't use the editing buttons. I am adding this detail to the question.